# Fetch Mysql data with Coma after each fetch C# Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to fetch the data from mysql data base Column where say i have multiple rows data for specific column and i need to include coma after each row fetch.

before it was giving the data when i tried to add coma

Current Output after adding code `Response.Write(name.Split(','));`

```
System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]System.String[]
```

My DB

```
Phone_Number              School_id

1                             SC1
2                             SC1
3                             SC1
4                             SC1
```

Expected Output

```
1,2,3,4
```

My Fetch Query

```
  string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Logging"].ConnectionString;


                using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
                {

                    using (MySqlCommand MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Phone_Number FROM Login  where SchoolId='" + SessionManager.SchoolId + "'", con))
                    {
                        MySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        con.Open();
                        MySqlDataReader MySqlDataReader = MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        while (MySqlDataReader.Read())
                        {

                            string name = MySqlDataReader["FatherFullName"].ToString();

                            Response.Write(name.Split(','));


                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Split` method splits your string with special character or string. This is not what you want.

You can add your `Phone_Number` values to a `List<string>` and you can use [`string.Join(string, IEnumerable<String>)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate comma separated values.

```
var list = new List<string>();
while(MySqlDataReader.Read())
{
   string name = MySqlDataReader["FatherFullName"].ToString();
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
   {
      list.Add(name);
   }
}
Response.Write(string.Join(",", list)); // 1,2,3,4
```

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Two things more;

- Default value `CommandType` is `Text`. You don't *need* to assign it explicitly.
- You don't need to close your connection with `con.Close()`. Since you used `using` statement, it does that automatically.

Comment: Thanks Exactly the same i was expecting now i got one more problem i think that u can sort it out the problem is say if there is a blank or null entrie's that returns `,,,,,,,,` like this

Comment: @Shaik You can check your string with [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) then. Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Sorry for asking one more question say if i want to avoid some text like by default saves in the db like`xxxx-xxx-xxxx` for that what should i do if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && !string.)

Comment: @Shaik This is for an another question. Not related this one.

Comment: sure i vl ask one more but wat i was thinking is like u bypassed null or empty rows thought u can do that also u should bypass only some specified text

Answer (score 1):

[String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to

> split a string into substrings based on the strings in an array

You can use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:-

```
//define a list of string
List<string> phoneNumbers = new List<string>();
while (MySqlDataReader.Read())
{
  //add all the phone numbers to the list
   string phoneNum = MySqlDataReader["FatherFullName"].ToString();
   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNum))
        phoneNumbers.Add(phoneNum);
}
 //finally use Join method to get expected result
Response.Write(String.Join(",",phoneNumbers));
```

Also, please note your query is open for [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you should consider using paramaterized query instead.

Answer (score 0):

Next to the split/join, you can also get the result from MySQL directly:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Phone_Number) FROM Login WHERE SchoolId = 'id';
```

This returns 1 single row with all phone numbers, seperated by comma's.